# Username and password not case sensitive

Tags: sql, database, passwords

I know that I am not storing my passwords in hash but for the purposes of this database, that doesn't matter.

The code references an SQL database that stores the passwords as plain text

Here's the code:

```
/*Checks to see if the username and password matcch the database
         If it does, it lets you in, if not you displays an error message*/
        string user = textBox1.Text.ToString();
        string pass = textBox2.Text;
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT COUNT(*) from Employees WHERE UserName = '"+(user)+ "' and Password = '"+(pass)+"' collate Latin1_Genral_CS_AS", conn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        if(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
        {
            HomeScreen home = new HomeScreen();
            this.Hide();
            home.ShowDialog();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Username or Password", "alter", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error );
        }
```

Comment: So what is your question? BTW `Latin1_Genral_CS_AS` (sic! note the missing e in general) is not a valid collation

Answer (score 1):

You can convert both the input values and table columns to `lowercase` or `uppercase`:

```
/*Checks to see if the username and password matcch the database
         If it does, it lets you in, if not you displays an error message*/
        string user = textBox1.Text.ToLower();
        string pass = textBox2.Text.ToLower();
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT COUNT(*) from Employees WHERE LOWER(UserName) = '"+(user)+ "' and LOWER(Password) = '"+(pass)+"' collate Latin1_Genral_CS_AS", conn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        if(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
        {
            HomeScreen home = new HomeScreen();
            this.Hide();
            home.ShowDialog();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Username or Password", "alter", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error );
        }
```

Comment: No need to convert, you can specify the collation with the query.

Comment: Yes, it could be another solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can `alter` your `database` to use the `collation` you wish:

```
ALTER DATABASE DBNAME CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

However, this will only apply on new tables. You can `alter` a `table` `column` to use the `collation` of your preference:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY column_name column_datatype COLLATE utf8_bin;
```